# Uauthorized when using service account to list Drive files on GSuite

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have an application that uses Google APIs. I created a service account for it, downloaded the keys and enabled domain-wide delegation for GSuite. The scopes include Drive.
I'm trying to iterate through the Drive files of GSuite users by using the service account to impersonate the users like this:

```
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

GoogleCredential.Builder builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)            
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(credFromJson(HTTP_TRANSPORT).getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES);
builder.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail);

GoogleCredential credential = builder.build();

return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

The GoogleCredential is created successfully. It has serviceAccountId, serviceAccountPrivateKey, serviceAccountUser and the needed scopes.

However when calling

```
driveService.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(*)").execute().getFiles();
```

I get 401 Unauthorized error.
I'm fairly sure that all the steps rearding the service account have been completed successfully, and domain-wide delegation is enabled, and even the credential seems okay. The scopes are certainly correct.
Where should I look next?

[image: details]

Answer (score 0):

> 401 Unauthorized error.

Means you dont have access. Why you dont have access is another question.  It could be the delegation setup or it could be your authentication.

Have you tried doing a file.list on the service accounts own account to see if its working at all. That will tell you if its an issue with your authorization or if its the gsuite setup.

But it looks to me like your not even setting credentials which will never work.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .createScoped(DriveScopes.all());

    // Construct the Analytics Reporting service object.
    return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Comment: It works with the service account's own account.

I think my code creates the credential with the GoogleCredential.Builder.build(). It's a credential for the service account.

I put it into separate lines:

Comment: I edited the post to put the credential into a separate line.

Comment: IF it works with the service account own account then the issue is with the delegation setup.

Comment: Yes, the problem must lay there.
I created the service account for the project, enabled domain-wide delegation and downloaded the key. After that I did the delegation itself in the admin consile, granting permission for the Drive API. Not sure which step could be missing, this was all that the Google guides described to do. But I must have missed something, because repeating the process did't make any difference.

Comment: I added the details of the Driver service: it has the credental, the scopes and the service account's user is set as one of the GSuite users.

Comment: I realized what the mistake was. First I created the authflow and the Directory service using the application's normal credentials.
Then I used the service account to build the Drive service.
However if I try to fix this by using the service account credentials to create the authflow it fails with IllegalArgumentException, most likely because the structure of the normal credentials.json for the application and the service account credential json is somewhat different.

Comment: The credentials.json has a key "installed" and it has the client id, secret, project id and other details as values.
The service account's credentials simply has the key-value pairs without being embedded into the "installed" object.

How am I supposed to use the service account's credential to build the auth flow?
Originally I thought it's okay if I build the auth flow with the application's credential because the service account belongs to the application anyway. But it seems that it's not sufficient.

Comment: there are three different types of credentials you can download from google developer console.  web, installed, and service account.  The code that uses them is different. The above code is for service account credentials you cant feed it a installed credentials.  Go check you have the correct type created.

Comment: you may like this https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/

Comment: Very informative website, thank you. I still haven't figured it all out because of unexpected errors, but now it's much more clear about the credentials.